# Check which styles are applied to an HTML element in a view in MVC 5 project

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

For example, let's say there is a markup with fancy colors:

```
<p>Something written here</p>
```

Using Visual Studio 2017 and a MVC 5 project, is there a way to check and locate which styles are currently being applied to it, and the CSS source file responsible for it?

Comment: You want to view styles that apply before seeing it in a web browser?  I don't think there are any tool that can correctly do that.  Is there an issue with using a browser?  (Chrome is really good at this)

Comment: Use your browser tools for that

Comment: Modern browsers have page inspector feature, you can use that to see CSS selectors applied for HTML tags & style files embedded in a page.

Comment: There's no problem in using browsers, just wondering if Visual Studio 2017 had a way for that. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Chrome, just right click your element, click inspect and it will open the dev tools. This shows the css applied and also which css stylesheet files it comes from.

You can't do this magically from VS, since JavaScript can change the stylesheet after the page is loaded, which VS doesn't know anything about since it isn't actually attempting to render it.